# How to concatenate echos

Tags: php

I want to know how can I concatenate both these echo's together:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['id'] ?><?php echo $sessionConcat ?>
```

I wanted it to concatenate the echos so that the concatenate echos can be then set to a variable, e.g.

```
$assessment = //concatenated echo
```

Comment: Google "php concatenate".  first result. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354595/php-operator-confusion-a-beginners-question/3354614 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484968/what-does-a-dot-do-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

```
$assignment = $_SESSION['id'] . $sessionConcat;
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.` operator is used to concatenate strings in PHP.

```
$assessment = $_SESSION['id'] . $sessionConcat;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change that code, just use use the . (dot) operator.

If You want to catch the output, use ob_start() (before) and ob_get_contents() (after), to get what normally would be echoed.