# concatenate wordpress option setting value to css class

Tags: php, css, wordpress, concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to concatenate echos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185950/how-to-concatenate-echos)

I want to concatenate wordpress option setting value (get_option('my_option_value') with css class in php file.
My css class are box-one ,box-two, box-three. While (get_option('my_option_value') gives value  one,two and three according to option setting.How can I concatenate class="box-"
and (get_option('my_option_value')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML, insert PHP inline with  :

```
 class="box-<?php echo get_option('my_option_value'); ?>" ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much. @barkadam.I am learner in php,so its nice to learn such a basics from yours answers.